# Workflow migration from repo to repo

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

I'd like to ask, how may I do a migration of mappings, worklets and workflows from Informatica PowerCenter Integ, to Prod.
Integ Enviroment and Prod are in different servers, so I can't just mouve folder from folder.

Is it possible? I can't find any refernece or tutorial.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Powercenter, its possible to copy form one env to another. Request everyone to check in their objects first adn log off from both source and target repo.

1. Open Repository Manager, connect to the source repository and select the folder you want to copy.
2. Click Edit > Copy.
3. Connect to the target repository. Connect to the target repository with the same user account used to connect to the source repository. If  you do not have same user you need to use deployment group/deployment folder.
4. In the Navigator, select the target repository, and click Edit > Paste. You will get many options like - replacing objects, use latest version, check out etc. You can follow below link to get help.
   https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/repository-guide/copying-folders-and-deployment-groups/copying-or-replacing-a-folder/steps-to-copy-or-replace-a-folder.html

Now, my preference would be to use deployment group or deployment folder. Its easy to use and easy to control - like if you want to replace 10 objects out of 100s, or you want to create a standard process for future migrations, or deploy using command task automatically, you can do as well.